# Element with event handler inside other element with another event handler?

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-8

I want to have a two event handlers `Panel_Tap` (`StackPanel` tap) and  `More_Tap` (`TextBlock` tap). `TextBlock` is inside the `StackPanel`. My xaml code:

```
  <StackPanel Tap="Panel_Tap" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image Height="75" Width="75" Source="{Binding Avatar}"/>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
           <TextBlock Name="Nickname" Text="{Binding Nickname}"/> 
           <TextBlock Name="More" Text="{Binding More}" Tap="More_Tap"/>
           <TextBlock Name="Text" Text="{Binding Text}"/>
        </StackPanel>
  </StackPanel>
```

If I tap `TextBlock` called first `More_Tap` then `Panel_Tap`. Is it possible by tap on the `TextBlock` call only `More_Tap` event handler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event keeps bubbling up the visual tree until it gets handled. So set `e.Handled = true` in the Tab event of the element where you want to prevent further bubbling of the event.

```cs
private void More_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e) {
  // Your code here...
  // ...

  e.Handled = true; // This line prevents this event from bubbling up
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you saved for me a lot of hours!